# Is there a way to listen specific fields for firestore functions?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to listen specific field changes in firestore functions or findout which field is updated? I have around 70 fields in each of my documents and i want my firebase function only do operations if some of the fields change (lets say the fields which starts with the name "number" like number01 , number02 and so on.I know i can write lots of if conditions to check this like

```
const newfieldvalue = change.after.data();
const previousfieldvalue = change.before.data();
if (newfieldvalue.number01 !== previousfieldvalue.number01){
   //do some operation here
}
```

but 40 of the 70 fields are like this and i dont want to write 40 if conditions to check this out.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  A Firestore onUpdate or onWrite function will trigger if any field in the document changes.  You have to examine the before and after snapshots to figure out what exactly changed.

Comment: Triggerring is not a problem actually, so you say there is no way to learn which field is updated unless i write lots of if conditions?

Comment: There might be an algorithm you can use to compare the objects, but Cloud Functions does not provide it.  If you're interested in more generalized solutions about how to compare or "diff" two objects that don't necessarily have anything to do with documents or functions, that sounds like a different thing to investigate.